# cast date to varchar then cast it back to date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, casting

I was working on a T-SQL query that someone else wrote and seen this.

```
AND Cast(m.MeasurementDateTime as date) >= cast('''+cast(@StartDate as varchar(100)) + ''' as date)
AND cast(m.MeasurementDateTime as date) <= cast('''+cast(@EndDate   as varchar(100)) + ''' as date)'
```

Why would someone do this? Am I missing something? Its the same thing as

```
CAST(@StartDate AS DATE)
```

right? 
The @EndDate and @StartDate are coming from a report so I don't the source data type.

Comment: Your guess is as good as any... Unless you can directly ask them or have some sample data (inputs and table values) to play with you will probably never find out.

Answer (score 3):

Can you print @StartDate to see its format? If it has an integer format for example we cannot cast it directly to a date:

```
select cast(20031016 as date)
Explicit conversion from data type int to date is not allowed.

select cast(cast(20031016 as varchar) as date)
16.10.2003 00:00:00
```

Comment: Nice use case. Terrible, terrible data model if they are using @startDate as an int, but nice catch for sure. +1 from me.